# What is the purpose of Red’s name carving in the Shawshank Redemption?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shawshank-redemption

In [*The Shawshank Redemption*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shawshank_Redemption) (1994), what is the purpose or significance of leaving your name on the wall?

Andy saw the previous names in his cell, and wanted to add his, however, Brooks in his new place carves his name before hanging himself. When Red sees Brooks’ name, he adds “so was Red.” There is no guarantee that anyone after Red will know who he is.

Now, the movie shows that Red occupied the same room as Brooks, but this was to show they were on a similar track, both being released from prison, taking the same job, it’s just that Red had hope of seeing Andy.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*They wanted to leave something behind -- anything however small.*

Brooks had been in prison for *fifty years*. The movie plot shows nothing of having family visit him or communicate with him. When he was paroled, he had only one friend on the outside, Jake the crow who never showed up. He had friends on the inside, but now they were cut off. Greater society shunned him, as the grocery double-bagging scene indicated. So he decided not to stay. He was going to be a man that had been *forgotten completely*. The only thing he could control was choosing his last day and leaving a mark with a pen knife. Brooks knew nobody would know who he was. He just wanted to leave the world just one tiny bit different.

Red was the same way, and would have probably had the same fate. But he had Andy. And that allowed Red to have his out. He left his mark also, but this time as a sign that this chapter of his life was over and there would be another one to begin.

Within the plot of the movie, the marks were not really about people understanding the who and why of it all. It was only about the fundamental concept of knowing you were here in this life, and left something -- however insignificant -- behind.

Cinematically, the stark contrast between the two marks makes for good, heartfelt drama.

Comment: This scene also very deliberately leads the audience to believe Red will hang himself like Brooks. This is important because it helps us feel how close Red came to the same fate. The actions needed to carve his name are unusual actions: pushing a chair into the center of the room, climbing on top of it. They show us these things in this order, just like they did with Brooks, and only at the last minute show us something that reveals that Red's intent is different than Brooks' was. It's done this way to evoke suspense and empathy.

Comment: @Tom True. The possibility that Red won't make it, and follow in Brooks' footsteps, begins its action (I believe) when Red looks into the pawn shop window. There are guns on display and that brings up Brooks' desire to shoot his boss and go back to prison. It's not until later we also note that compasses were also on display in the window. The choice is solidified when we see the compass in Red's hand (instead of a gun). Red is lucky that he had the choice to accept Andy's help (Brooks did not).